# Xamarin forms lower case button on preview in designer? (Custom components are not being rendered)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an app with a button with text that says 'click me'.

I made this into a lowercase text by adding the code in the **resources.Android file of my xamarin forms.**

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```

It's uppercase on the designer but when deploying it's  what I want. But I also want it to be lowercase in the designer so I can see what's going on.

**Designer**
[image]

**Deployment**
I don't know how to take screnshot on phone but just imagine it as the image above but lower case.

So I want it to also be lowercase in the designer. How do I do this?

This also applies when I import  custom fonts. This is how it looked like for my friend but not for me:

[image]

I'm also getting this which could be the cause of the problem:
[image]

**I'M LOOKING FOR A XAMARIN.FORMS SOLTUON. NOT NATIVE. THANK YOU**
Thanks,

Hello Leo, I am getting this error:

Maybe I will enable hot reload?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have looked at the source code, you will find that in theme `Theme.AppCompat`, the default property `<item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>` of `appcompat.widget.Button` is true.

You could write a CustomRenderer to change it.

Create a `CustomButtonRenderer` in your Android project and `SetAllCaps(false)`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace your namepace
{
  class CustomButtonRenderer :ButtonRenderer
  {
     public CustomButtonRenderer(Context context):base(context)
     {

     }


     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
      {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetAllCaps(false);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

```
<Button WidthRequest="100" Text="Login" />
```

before using customrenderer

[image]

after using customrenderer

[image]

Comment: Will have a go. Thanks!

Comment: @tommy99 If it is helpful to you,could you mark it as an accept answer.Thanks!

Comment: Hello Leo, seems as though I'm getting some obsolete warnings from this code. It also doesn't seem to be changing in the designer. How would I implement this? Maybe give me some more detail regarding that. speak tomorrow, got to go now.

Comment: Hey Leo Zhu, I'm not entirely sure if you've tested your own code? NOTE: I'm getting an error that custom components are not being rendered? I've tried to do this and the button is still lowercase in the designer? Contact me on Discord and we can chat further:TechDogTom#1845. Thanks.

Comment: @tommy99 Yes,i test it and it works for me,and the  warning you could ignore, it seems to be a vs previewer issue.Did you add assembly attribute at the top of your namepace?

Comment: Can you maybe tell me how to initialise this in the app itself - sorry I am new to xamarin forms maybe provide a code for the initialisation? Or contact me on discord.

Comment: @tommy99 No initialization is required, you just create the above class under the Android project and then copy the code.